# Connection string without User Id or Password

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have defined a database with no username and password in SQL Server. Here is my connection string where I do not know what I should set in my `User Id` and `password`:

```
db = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Scheduling_Employee;User ID=;Password=;");
```

Comment: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;` See: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: if you use SQL server authentication while logging into SSMS then put that as user name and password, if its windows authentication just set  Integrated Security=SSPI;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can use the trusted connection,

for example,

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Refer to this url for all other combinations http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 2):

For your local machine you should be able to set the parameter Integrated Security = true;

That would allow you to use the windows authentication.